# Access VBA/macro - apply nested filters

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working in Microsoft Access with both VBA code and macros.

Table 1 (PlayerList) - contains a list of MLB players and teamID they play for
Table 2 (TeamList) - contains a list of MLB teams (and teamIDs) and the league they are in (e.g., NL East)

Form contains a combo box where the user can select the league, and I want to see all the players in that league (on my subform).  This requires a lookup of all teams in the selected league then all players on those teams.  I've explored ApplyFilter and SearchForRecord.  I don't see how to nest the query.  My searches for nested and multiple searches hasn't pointed to an answer.

Comment: I added a couple of fields from TeamList in the form of PlayerList linking them by teamID, then looked at the form in data sheet view and was able to filter on league, team, etc.

Answer (score 0):

- in subform set recordsource as following (adjust based on your table and field names)

```sql
SELECT T1.Name
FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.TeamID=T2.TeamID
WHERE (((Table1.LEAGUE)=[Forms]![Main]![LeagSelectText].[VALUE]));
```

what it does is it will  query results using filter defined in Main form (League for example)

- add event (click button or combo box (let's call it ComboLeague) change and add follwoing line to it

```vb
Private Sub ComboLeague_Change()
 Form_SubForm.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great start.  My form contains other combo boxes as well, such as city (show all players from teams in selected city).  Thus, I'm not able to set the recordsource for the subform based on one selection.

Comment: You can set recorsource in vba as well.Based on condition you can set `Form_SubF.RecordSource`  to different  sql  just before requery